# Changing prompts for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I'm doing an exercise where I have to ask the user for 5 integer inputs and then print the total of the 5 numbers. I have to do this using a `for` loop. I know how to do this with a `while` loop but we're currently learning about `for` loops.

I have written the following code:

```
num = 0
count = 0

for i in range(num):
    while count < 5: 
        num = getInteger("Please enter a number: ", format(num + 1))
        count += 1
        print(num)
    total = num + num
print(total)
```

Though I get so many errors because frankly, I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: Is `getInteger` a function you've defined or imported? If so, please include that in the code in your question.

Comment: Please read the documentation on both *how to get input from the user* and *looping in python*. Know what you do and why you do it, first rule of programming.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
total=0
for i in range(5):
   num = int(input(f"Please enter number {i+1}: "))
   total+=num
print(total)
```

Comment: (In addition to ignoring parts of the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings),) You missed the point of the question(/exercise): how to prompt for *number 1*,  *number 2*, … *number 5*.

Comment: Thank you @greybeard for your feedback, I have edited my answer

Comment: Thanks @Walid this helped a lot! I had something similar like that before but like I said I have no idea what i'm doing *sigh*.